# MapPolaris and showing point bubble using button maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Polaris map library in my android app.
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris

I've Google Map with some geo points. I'm reading them from database. I've added two buttons on the map activity - "next" and "previous" to navigate between points.

mc.animateTo(geopoints.get(arrayID));
*"arrayID" is the id of the next geo point and "mc" is map controller.*

It works great but I want to add one more feature.

I want annotation to be visible by default while moving between points. After click on the "next" button I want to be moved to the next point on my map and it's annotation should be  visible (not only after clicking on it).

Probably there is an easy way to do it.

I should probably do something with calloutView but I can't figure it out how to do that.

I made something like this. But it's not working properly.

```
MapCalloutView calloutView;
calloutView = new MapCalloutView(getApplicationContext());
calloutView.setDisclosureEnabled(true);
calloutView.setClickable(true);     calloutView.setLeftAccessoryView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.accessory, calloutView, false));
calloutView.show(mMapView, geopoints.get(arrayID), false);
calloutView.setData(annotations.get(arrayID));
```

It is showing me bubble but it creates new calloutView which is wrong I think. For example Polaris listeners are not working. I can't deselect callout etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! It was so easy...

I don't need to play with MapcalloutView in Polaris.

```
mMapView.setSelectedAnnotation(arrayID);
```